# App_Offline dynamically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, app-offline.htm

I have a MVC5 web application on production, but I had to call the server guy to take down the site manually everytime I need to publish new features, just wondering if I can do this dynamically without any access to the webserver. I was thinking of programatically rename the App_Offline file but it won't work if I want to turn the site back on since ASP.NET automatically block any request.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried just overwrite/publish over the live site, maybe it not harmful.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not harmful but I still want to be able to take the site down without having to call the server guy.

Comment: Let's say you could rename the file from ASP .Net, but how will you do it after ASP .Net is offline when it won't process any request? The only way is to do it outside the website process like from another website which you will create to do the rename.